# Does browser stop/crash halts script execution?

Tags: php

I mean, if a php script/page is invoked by a browser and page load/execution is interrupted by user or by browser crash, does script execution continues on the server side?

Answer (score 14):

yes, unless you call ignore_user_abort() first. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: You may also change default behavior in config file: http://pl.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort

Answer (score 1):

Depends on [ignore_user_abort](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)() setting

Answer (score 1):

Depends on `ignore_user_abort()`. But if you have some loop or poorly written code, it will run until script timeout / max execution time has been reached (~30 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

You can test this very easily:

```
echo "sleeping 10 seconds...";
sleep(10); //close your browser at this point
error_log("i'm still here!");
```

Just check your web server error log for the output.